# Linux, adding sub-interfaces

Tags: linux, networking

I'll start out by saying networking isn't my strong suit, I'm trying to configure a few sub-interfaces so that some code I am working will have more sockets to locally bind to. So far i've done the following, I can locally bind to my sub interface 192.168.2.210, but I can not make a remote connection with it.

Here is my ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:BB:00:0B  
          inet addr:10.6.19.18  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:febb:b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1056026 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:638290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:237037186 (226.0 MiB)  TX bytes:126161362 (120.3 MiB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:BB:00:0B  
          inet addr:192.168.2.210  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Here is what i've tried to do to configure eth0:1

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.2.210/32 up
ip route add 192.168.2.210/32 via 10.6.19.18
```

Here is my netstat -r output:

```
192.168.2.210   devserv.        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.6.19.0       *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
default         10.6.19.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for looking

Comment: Please clarify what youre trying to do a bit more. Youre adding `192.168.2.210/32` which means that IP address has no network. The `/32` netmask says that its the only IP address in the subnet. Also youre adding a route to say that traffic to that IP should go out your `10.6.19.18` address. This doesnt make any sense. Why would you add a route to an IP that is on the server itself? If you can provide more info about what youre trying to accomplish, we can probably help more.

Comment: "some code I am working will have more sockets to locally bind to" - note that there is an OS-imposed limit of sockets per process, which you may be able to increase, but adding more interfaces won't help unless you really need more than 60,000 sockets...

Comment: I need to be able to bind to 600,000 unique local socket pairs and establish a connection on each to a remote system. A previous system I was working on already had this networking setup using 12 sub interfaces (binding on ports 10,000-60,000 for each interface), I no longer have access to this particular server and I just need to recreate the networking configuration.

Comment: You need more ip numbers from your real net, that is eth0:0 => 10.6.19.19, eth0:1 => 10.6.19.20 and so on. I wonder if they are available for you tho. You don't need to set routes then.

Answer (score 5):

Ditch ifconfig as this is being phased out for the iproute2 package;

```
root@bensley-n2:~# ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:6d:0a:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:ea:3a:ad:2e:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::76ea:3aff:fead:2e00/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether ce:70:78:f8:10:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
root@bensley-n2:~# ip address add 1.1.1.1/24 dev wlan0
root@bensley-n2:~# ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:6d:0a:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:ea:3a:ad:2e:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
    inet 1.1.1.1/24 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::76ea:3aff:fead:2e00/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether ce:70:78:f8:10:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
root@bensley-n2:~# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
1.1.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 1.1.1.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.5 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
```

(You can abbreviate the `ip` commands: `ip address add` can be shortened all the way down to `ip a a`, and `ip address show` can be shortened to `ip a s`. `show` is the default action if you don't specify the second argument, so you can just type `ip a` if you want to be really terse.)

You don't need to add a route either for a local subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, sockets aren't actually bound to an interface -- they're bound to an IP address. Virtual/alias interfaces are deprecated and should be avoided -- you should rather add multiple IP addresses directly to `eth0`. Secondly, if you want these addresses to be routable on the local network you need to use addresses on that network (i.e. 10.6.19.0/24) and not a machine-local subnet like 192.168.2.0/24 (unless you can get the router or the remote machines reconfigured with this other subnet). To add additional address, use the following command:

```
ip addr add 10.6.19.19/24 dev bond0
```

You shouldn't require any additional routing configuration since the addresses are on an existing subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding more addresses, which is going to get a little complicated, why dont your sockets use different ports?

Comment: I need to bind a total of 600,000 sockets, I bind on port 10,000 - 60,000 for each interface, I need 12 of these sub interfaces so I can reach my total.

Comment: Then you need to add a gateway on the same subnet, ie in the 192.168.2.0/24. What route does the 'remote' machine take to get to this network? If it is via the 10.6.19.0/24 youll have to enable ip forwarding on this server too. But 600,000 open sockets and routing... ouch.